# Kubernetes pull from multiple private docker registries

Tags: docker, kubernetes

To use a docker container from a private docker repo, kubernetes recommends creating a secret of type 'docker-registry' and referencing it in your deployment.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

Then in your helm chart or kubernetes deployment file, use `imagePullSecrets`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template: 
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      containers:
      - name: foo
        image: foo.example.com
```

This works, but requires that all containers be sourced from the same registry.

**How would you pull 2 containers from 2 registries** (e.g. when using a sidecar that is stored separate from the primary container) ?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template: 
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: foo
        image: foo.example.com
        imagePullSecrets:
        - name: foo-secret
      - name: bar
        image: bar.example.com
        imagePullSecrets:
        - name: bar-secret
```

I've tried creating 2 secrets `foo-secret` and `bar-secret` and referencing each appropriately, but I find it fails to pull both containers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to include `imagePullSecrets:` directly at the pod level, but you can have multiple secrets there.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template: 
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: foo-secret
      - name: bar-secret
      containers:
      - name: foo
        image: foo.example.com/foo-image
      - name: bar
        image: bar.example.com/bar-image
```

The [Kubernetes documentation on this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod) notes:

> If you need access to multiple registries, you can create one secret for each registry. Kubelet will merge any `imagePullSecrets` into a single virtual `.docker/config.json` when pulling images for your Pods.